# Python code not waiting for Tweepy wait_on_rate_limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

I am using the Tweepy Twitter API and Python to retrieve a fairly large number of tweets (~40,000) using this code:

```
def getTweets(query, num):
#gets the specified number of tweets
_max_queries = 100

tweets = tweet_batch = api.search(q=query, count=num, tweet_mode='extended')
ct = 1
while len(tweets) < num and ct < _max_queries:
    print("Got %d tweets!" % (len(tweets)))
    tweet_batch = api.search(q=query, count=num-len(tweets), max_id=tweet_batch.max_id, tweet_mode='extended')
    tweets.extend(tweet_batch)
    ct += 1
return tweets
```

I have api wait_on_rate_limit set to true. Immediately, after I call the getTweets() function I attempt to process the tweets. Only problem is that Python is not waiting for Tweepy's rate limit to reset and is proceeding with executing the process code prematurely. For example, if I try to pull 20,000 tweets Tweepy pulls about 9,000 and immediately processes them rather than waiting for the rate limit to reset, and pulling the rest of the tweets. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set the wait_on_rate_limit in api object declaration?

Comment: @NishantPatel yes I did. I'm not sure what else I should do.